# Trying to understand function fma() and its special features

Tags: c

I look for understanding the C standard library function called `fma` included from `math.h`, and I know it deals with performance and optimizes a multiplication plus a number.

I would like to know when `fma` gives different results. Apparently the function differs slightly from the non-optimized expression.

And what is that about only one rounding instead of two rounding operations?

Comment: Isn't it function ```fma()``` in header file ```math.h``` and not ```FMA``` library in ```standard C```?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add

Comment: This question is clear and should be reopened. It is readily answered by explaining that, using two-digit decimal floating-point for example, `11*11 - 120` yields 0, because `11*11` rounds to 120, and then subtracting 120 yields 0, whereas `fma(11, 11, -120)` calculates 11•11 = 121 without rounding and then subtracts 120, yielding 1.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: `fma` is declared in `<math.h>` and may be implemented in as a macro in the header but also must be implemented as a function in the standard C library.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: Re your proposed edit: FMA is a proper abbreviation for the fused-multiply-add operation. We may use FMA to refer to the operation and `fma` to refer to the C library function that performs that operation.

Comment: Please don't make cosmetic edits to closed questions; you are only likely to attract additional downvotes by inviting new visitors to review your question, and conclude that it is still unfocused.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Here you go 

Answer (score 1):

Let *a*, *b*, and *c* denote the values of variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. In this answer, expressions in `code font` denote programming computations, and expressions not in code font denote mathematical expressions, using real-number arithmetic. This answer uses two-digit decimal floating-point for examples, in which .012, .12, 1.2, 12, and 120 are representable but 1.23 and 123 are not.

The program expression `a + b` produces Round(*a*+*b*), where Round is a function that takes a real number and produces the nearest value representable in the floating-point format in the direction determined by a selected rounding method. For example, using round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, Round(1.23) is 1.2. (The actual implementation of `a + b` will use an algorithm with some fixed number of digits, but we discuss its required results using real-number arithmetic.)

The ordinary evaluation of `a*b+c` is Round(Round(*ab*) + *c*). That is, `a*b` is performed as one floating-point operation, which produces a result as if the operands were multiplied using real-number arithmetic and then rounded to a representable value, and then `c` is added as a second floating-point operation, which also produces a result rounded to a representable value. Thus, this sequence has two rounding operations.

The evaluation of `fma(a, b, c)` is Round(*ab* + *c*). That is, the result is as if the combined expression were evaluated using real-number arithmetic and then rounded to a representable value. This sequence has only one rounding operation.

For example, in `11*11 + -120`, `11*11` produces 0 because 11•11 = 121 and 120 is the nearest representable value to that. Then adding −120 produces 0, which is not affected by rounding because it is representable. However, `fma(11, 11, -120)` produces 1 because 11•11 + −120 = 1, and rounding leaves that as 1 since it is representable. There was no intermediate rounding of 11•11.

This operation, called Fused Multiply-Add and abbreviated FMA, is primarily thought of as providing easier access to more precision rather than as a function for performance. It may result in faster-performing programs because, without it, some programs would have to use more cumbersome operations to get the desired results.

A key use is that FMA can be used to get **all** the bits of a product. Consider multiplying `a` and `b`. `a*b` produces only a rounded result. For example, 12•34 is 4108, but `12*34` produces 4100. However, consider this code:

```
h = a*b;
l = fma(a*b, -h);
```

This will put 4100 in `h`, and then, for `fma(a*b, -h)`, 12•34 + −4100 is computed, and that produces 8. Thus, with 4100 in `h` and 8 in `l`, the program has the complete product of `a` and `b`, 4108.